# Add separator to textarea values if there is more than one existing (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and wish to append a textarea with some values on click.
Already managed how to add them using the snippet below but I need an update for it.

Basically, if there is more than one values in there, when clicking the "button" for the next value, it should insert a separator "|" , which can be set in form of a prefix or something.

Example behaviour:

I have an empty textarea with the id "attribute15" and few spans with the values: "Red" "Green" "Blue".
When i click on each of the spans the textarea is filled with "RedGreenBlue".
However, I want that if I already clicked the "Red", when going for the next value, it automatically adds a "|" separator between values so it becomes "Red|Green|Blue".

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Here is my current snippet

```
  $(".<?php echo 'attribute15'; ?>").click(function(){
    var txt = $.trim($(this).text());
    var box = $("#<?php echo 'attribute15'; ?>");
    box.val(box.val() + txt);
  });
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my original post and added the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check for if the `textarea` already has text inside it, and then append a `|` if there is.

```
if (box.val().length > 0)
    box.val(box.val() + "|" + txt);
else
    box.val(txt);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @4castle , that did the job !